# Client isolation in Ubuntu with hostapd

Tags: 12.04, wireless, iptables, hostapd

We have created a wifi hotspot or a wireless access point using `hostapd` in Ubuntu. How can we isolate wifi clients the same way "Client Isolation" does in some access points? Is there any way we can combine `iptables` with `hostapd` to apply some firewall rules between wifi clients?

Answer (score 0):

Create an iptables rule on input and output that allows the source address range to talk to the router/default gateway, additional rules for any servers or other resources on that subnet.

Create a final rule that drops packets between the source address range and the source address range.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $WIFI -o $WIFI -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $WIFI -o $WIFI -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d $SOMESERVERIP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $WIFI -o $WIFI -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d $SOMEOTHERSERVERIP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $WIFI -o $WIFI -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

The basics of this chain of events is:

1. if it's in the subnet and it's talking to the gateway, accept it
2. If it's in the subnet and it's talking to a server, accept it
3. Rule 2 repeats until you run out of acceptable servers
4. If it's in the subnet and it's talking to anything else in the subnet, drop it

Answer (score 0):

At this time, `iptables` rules have no effect on the packets forwarded directly by the wifi interface, according to [this](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=159319486825750&w=2).

Good news is that Hostapd 2.9 has a an option called `ap_isolate` that does exactly what you described. You can read about it [here](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf).

Once you set that flag, all packets from devices on the access point network will be dropped by the access point.